Rename sharepoint folder with MS Graph API
I am trying to find out how to use MS Graph API to rename a folder on Sharepoint based on the name of a folder.
Unfortunately without success so far.
The folder I would like to rename is below folder:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
I've been going through the references on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/list?view=graph-rest-1.0 but no idea which one to use and how...
Anyone that can point me in the right direction?
Thx
Frederik

update 03/05/2024
I tried the link of Tiny Wang:
Microsoft Graph API - Getting files by file path - 404 Not Found
My file is here:
[![enter image description here][2]][2]
And this is my API call, throwing error 'itemNotFound':
[![enter image description here][3]][3]
I still don't see what I am doing wrong :-(

update 2 03/05/2024
Ok, this is stupid.... I found what was going wrong...
I was testing with Graph Explorer with the wrong microsoft account...
Stupid ofcourse, I could slap myself, but in case anyone would experience the same as me...
CHECK THE ACCOUNT YOU ARE LOGGED IN TO in Graph explorer and see if the account you are logged in with has the appropriate authorizations!
In case somebody would be interested:
Endpoint to get the id of my folder
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{YOURSITE}.sharepoint.com/drives/{DRIVE_ID}/items/root:/01 PROJECTEN DOCS/03 ADMIN en TECHN DOC PROJ/TEST/_ABC_AX_WEB
Endpoint to update the name of the folder:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{YOURSITE}.sharepoint.com/drives/{DRIVEID}/items/{ITEMID}
in the body:
{
"name": "ABC"
}
This changes the name of folder _ABC_AX_WEB to ABC
({ITEMID} is retrieved with the 1st call)

have you tried this API? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Do you know drive id, sharepoint site id, list id?

The only thing I know is the path.

Then pls do like what this answer showed using path: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55007087

Thx @TinyWang, i've updated my original post to show what i 've tried based on the link you shared

could you pls firstly to list all items in the root folder, then locate your file step by step? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request

@TinyWang, I've added another update to my original post.
Thanks a lot for your help and time!

Thanks for your reply and it looks to be resolved. Pls allow me to summarize your result below to end this question!

Thanks OP for sharing the result.
Firstly, we could use this API to update the file name which request is PATCH /sites/{site-id}/drive/items/{item-id}。
Then we need to get the item ID based on the file folder, we can use this request /sites/{siteId}/drive/root:/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/photo.jpg.
We should also pay attention to the account signed-in when we use Graph Explorter.
